# React State not updating when mapping list items

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am making a Spotify clone, currently making the liked songs page. Here is the screenshot of my page:

[image: screenshot of page]

The problem here is that I need the footer (the player) to update whenever a song is clicked, but React is not updating the state of my functions:

So far I tried passing props and everything, and although it console logs when I click the i button the state does not update. It only updates on the last list item.

Note: Ignore the requests to backend for now I have made a temp json array that I am using.

I need this to work so that I can pass the song link, song name and artist name whenever an li is clicked. Also I am new to React and do not exactly know how functions/components communicate between each other.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./LikedSongs.css";
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Footer from "./Footer";

function Song(props) {
  const [songname, setSongname] = useState("");
  const [artist, setArtist] = useState("-");
  const [songlink, setSonglink] = useState("");

  function handleSong(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("working");
    console.log(props.name);
    console.log(props.artist);
    setArtist(props.artist);
    setSongname(props.name);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <li className="songItem" onClick={handleSong}>
        <span>{props.count}</span>
        {/* <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="Alan"> */}
        <h5>
          {props.name}
          <div className="subtitle">{props.artist}</div>
        </h5>
        <div className="album">{props.album}</div>
      </li>
      <div className="footer">
        <div className="footer_left">
          <img
            className="footer_albumLogo"
            src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-aHWeKTP05eBf-0-t500x500.jpg"
            alt=""
          />

          <div className="footer_songInfo">
            <h6>{songname}</h6>
            <p>{artist}</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="footer_center">
          <img className="shuffle" src={require("./shuffle.png")} alt="" />
          <img className="back" src={require("./back.png")} alt="" />
          <img
            className="playbutton"
            src={require("./playbutton.png")}
            alt=""
          />
          <img className="next" src={require("./next.png")} alt="" />
          <img className="repeat" src={require("./repeat.png")} alt="" />
          {/* <img className="pause" src={require("./pause.png")} alt=""/> */}
        </div>

        <div className="footer_right">
          <img className="volume" src={require("./volume.png")} alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function LikedSongs() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const songs1 = fetchdata();
  });

  async function fetchdata() {
    const songs = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/songs");
    return songs.data;
  }

  const songs = [
    {
      songname: "On my way",
      artistname: "Alan Walker",
      Albumname: "On my way",
    },
    {
      songname: "horse",
      artistname: "chickrees",
      Albumname: "On my way",
    },
    {
      songname: "On my way",
      artistname: "Alan Walker",
      Albumname: "On my way",
    },
    {
      songname: "On my way",
      artistname: "Alan Walker",
      Albumname: "On my way",
    },
    {
      songname: "On my way",
      artistname: "Alan Walker",
      Albumname: "On my way",
    },
  ];

  var count = 1;
  songs.forEach((song) => {
    song["count"] = count;
    count++;
  });

  {
    /* <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="Alan"> */
  }
  return (
    <div className="songsbody">
      <Sidebar />
      <div className="listsongs">
        <li className="songItem top">
          <span>#</span>
          <h5>Song name</h5>
          <div className="album">Album name</div>
        </li>
        {songs &&
          songs.map((song) => (
            <Song
              key={song.count}
              count={song.count}
              name={song.songname}
              album={song.Albumname}
              artist={song.artistname}
            />
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: you could use react context to share state across multiple components more easily, have a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: You need to "lift the state up". I assume you have a component that wraps your liked songs (sidebar), the main content, and the footer. That wrapper component should keep the currently selected song in its state and pass it down to other components that need it. The easiest way to do this is to move the useState() statements up to the wrapper component and then pass the song/artist down via props.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some problems.

1. It's not good to write your footer inside Song component. Because the footer does not belong to a single Song.
2. You should declare your state in parent component (LikedSongs) and also the onClick function.
3. No need to declare any other states in the Song component.
4. No need to pass each song property one by one. Instead pass the whole song object to the Song component as a property.
5. Your useEffect must run only once so you should pass an empty array as the dependency.

So this will help you:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./LikedSongs.css";
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Footer from "./Footer";

function Song(props) {
  function handleSong(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.handleSongClick(props.song);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <li className="songItem" onClick={handleSong}>
        <span>{props.song.count}</span>
        <h5>
          {props.song.songname}
          <div className="subtitle">{props.song.artistname}</div>
        </h5>
        <div className="album">{props.song.Albumname}</div>
      </li>
    </div>
  );
}

const initialValueOfSongs = [
  {
    songname: "On my way",
    artistname: "Alan Walker",
    Albumname: "On my way",
  },
  {
    songname: "horse",
    artistname: "chickrees",
    Albumname: "On my way",
  },
  {
    songname: "On my way",
    artistname: "Alan Walker",
    Albumname: "On my way",
  },
  {
    songname: "On my way",
    artistname: "Alan Walker",
    Albumname: "On my way",
  },
  {
    songname: "On my way",
    artistname: "Alan Walker",
    Albumname: "On my way",
  },
];

export default function LikedSongs() {
  const [selectedSong, setSelectedSong] = useState(initialValueOfSongs[0]);
  const [songs, setSongs] = useState(initialValueOfSongs);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchdata();
  }, []);

  async function fetchdata() {
    const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/songs");
    const songs = response.data;
    var count = 1;
    songs.forEach((song) => {
      song["count"] = count;
      count++;
    });
    setSongs(songs);
  }

  const handleSongClick = (song) => {
    setSelectedSong(song);
  }

  return (
    <div className="songsbody">
      <Sidebar />
      <div className="listsongs">
        <li className="songItem top">
          <span>#</span>
          <h5>Song name</h5>
          <div className="album">Album name</div>
        </li>
        {songs &&
          songs.map((song) => (
            <Song
              key={song.count}
              song={song}
              handleSongClick={handleSongClick}
            />
          ))}
      </div>
      <div className="footer">
        <div className="footer_left">
          <img
            className="footer_albumLogo"
            src="https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-aHWeKTP05eBf-0-t500x500.jpg"
            alt=""
          />

          <div className="footer_songInfo">
            <h6>{selectedSong.songname}</h6>
            <p>{selectedSong.artistname}</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="footer_center">
          <img className="shuffle" src={require("./shuffle.png")} alt="" />
          <img className="back" src={require("./back.png")} alt="" />
          <img
            className="playbutton"
            src={require("./playbutton.png")}
            alt=""
          />
          <img className="next" src={require("./next.png")} alt="" />
          <img className="repeat" src={require("./repeat.png")} alt="" />
        </div>

        <div className="footer_right">
          <img className="volume" src={require("./volume.png")} alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. Please pick my answer as the correct answer if it's possible.